# PHP design and if statment html output

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with structure in PHP. The problem is when I style using Bootstrap the if statement structure is weird. What I a trying to do is check if the user is logged in display the following content: 
[If the user is logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uONu2.jpg)

However when he logs out it should just show:
You are not logged in.

However this is what happens:
[When logged out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx6tj.jpg)

Here is my following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    // session variables into local variables.
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $result = "Welcome back! <br>".$username. "<br> You are tester number: ".$id;
    $result .= ' <br> <button class="btn" type="button" onclick=window.parent.location.href="logout.php" target="_parent">Log out</button>';

    } else {
        $result = "You are not logged in yet";

    }

?>
<?php
echo $result;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Welcome - <?php echo $username ;?></title>
      <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="../js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>


  </head>
  <body>
        <div class = "container">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                  Comment
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
              <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>
                <button class="btn" type="button" onclick=window.parent.location.href="blog/post.php" target="_parent">Comment</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                  Collapsible Group Item #2
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
              <div class="panel-body">

                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                  Collapsible Group Item #3
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you **should not** display anything outside of the HTML `<body>`.

Second, you should do your condition inside the `<body>` like that (it's far from a perfect example, it's just an idea) :

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome - <?php echo $username ;?></title>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        echo "You are not logged in yet";
    }
    else {
        // session variables into local variables.
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $result = "Welcome back! <br>".$username. "<br> You are tester number: ".$id;
        $result .= ' <br> <button class="btn" type="button" onclick=window.parent.location.href="logout.php" target="_parent">Log out</button>';

        echo $result;
?>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                  Comment
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
              <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>
                <button class="btn" type="button" onclick=window.parent.location.href="blog/post.php" target="_parent">Comment</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                  Collapsible Group Item #2
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
              <div class="panel-body">

                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                  Collapsible Group Item #3
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<?php
    }
?>
  </body>
</html>
```